# Parallelism between quantum density matrix and a probability distribution in classical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, probability, density-operator, phase-space

In quantum statistical mechanics we often define a density matrix as

$\rho = \sum_{i} p_{i} | \Psi_{i} \rangle \langle \Psi_{i} | $.

Its time volution is determined by the equation:

$\rho \left(t\right) = U \left(t\right) \rho U^{\dagger} \left( t \right)  $ and it allows us to determine the expectation value of any observable $O$ of the system at any time as

$\langle O (t) \rangle = \mathrm{Tr} \left[ \rho(t) O \right] $. Defining Heisenberg's time evolution as $O(t)=U^{\dagger} \left( t \right) O U \left( t \right) $ it is easy to see the following two things:

1. $\langle O \rho(t) \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}\left[ \rho O(t) \right] $
2. $ \mathrm{Tr} \left[ \rho(t) O(t) \right] = \mathrm{Tr}\left[ \rho O \right]  $

Number two is particularly interesting as it means that time evolution of both the probability distribution and the observable leaves measurements unchanged.

I tried to take this as a starting point for a statistical description of classical mechanics. I therefore defined a "classical state" as a probability distribution over the phase space $(\textbf{Q}, \textbf{P} )$: $\phi ( \textbf{Q} , \textbf{P})$. I know how observables evolve in classical mechanics: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_{t} \left(  \textbf{Q}, \textbf{P} \right) = \left\{f_{t} , H \right\} $. Using relation 2) (which I expect to be true in classical physics as well) I define the classical state at time $t$ such that:

$constant = \int d\textbf{Q} d\textbf{P} \phi_{t} ( \textbf{Q} , \textbf{P}) f_{t} \left(  \textbf{Q}, \textbf{P} \right) $. By deriving both sides of the equation in $t$ and substituting the classical equations of motion for the function $f_{t} $ I get:

$0 = \int d\textbf{Q} d\textbf{P} \left[ \dot{\phi}_{t} f_{t}  + \phi_{t} \right\{f_{t} , H \left\}   \right] $. By expanding Poisson's brackets, integrating by parts in N dimensions, and equating the integrand to zero I get to the equation:

$\dot{\phi}_{t} =  \left\{ \phi_{t}, H \right\} $, which kind of looks like Liouville's theorem but it's not because it's missing a $-$ sign in front of the brackets. I expected to get exactly Liouville's theorem and I don't understand what went wrong. Maybe relation 2) doesn't work in classical mechanics, or it needs a little fixing, for example if I claim
$constant = \int d\textbf{Q} d\textbf{P} \phi_{-t} ( \textbf{Q} , \textbf{P}) f_{t} \left(  \textbf{Q}, \textbf{P} \right) $ instead, I should get Liouville's theorem. Maybe I have to reverse time?

Comment: What is the physical meaning of the left hand side of your equation 2? Aside from being trivially equivalent to the right hand side, I am not aware of any way to make physical sense of mixing Heisenberg and Schrodinger pictures like this. Consequently I am very suspicious of asserting that it can (or at least can naively) be applied in classical physics.

Comment: I was hoping one could just take it straight to classical physics using the parallelism between density matrix and its evolution (which is governed by a quantum Liouvulle theorem) and the probability distribution in classical physics (which is governed by a classical Liouvulle theorem). I think it might be easier to interpret the equation $constant = \int d\textbf{Q} d\textbf{P} \phi_{-t} f_{t} $ as "evolving the state backwards and the observables forwards leaves everything unchanged". It should also give Liouville's theorem but it's disturbing to me that 2) holds only in QM.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. $ \mathrm{Tr} \left[ \rho(t) O(t) \right] = \mathrm{Tr}\left[ \rho O \right]  $
>
> Number two is particularly interesting as it means that time evolution of both the probability distribution and the observable leaves measurements unchanged.

This is a false premise. In quantum mechanics the evolution operator affects **either** the density matrix (in the Schrödinger picture) **or** the operators (in the Heisenberg picture), but not both.

Comment: Yes, of course, but nothing prohibits us from "making the mistake" of evolving both and seeing what happens. In QM it is found that the expectation value should remain constant under this transformation (which at this point isn't a time evolution anymore but something else entirely). I assumed it would apply in classical mechanics as well and from there I tried to derive Liouville's theorem

Comment: Indeed, nothing prohibits you from using incorrect premises. What does happen is that whatever you derive will also be incorrect.

Comment: But equation 2) is correct in QM, so it would make sense for it to have a classical analogue we could use.

Comment: No, equation 2 is **not** correct in QM. You are mixing time evolutions from two different pictures. To get correct results, you need to use the same picture for everything.

Comment: But it trivially holds, as can be proven using basic proprieties of the trace and the definition of time evolution for a density matrix and for an observable.

Comment: @Masterme I don't see any point in repeating myself. The equation is incorrect, since it is using its ingredients out of context. There is no correct understanding of QM in which $\rho(t) = U(t) \rho U^{\dagger}(t)$ and $O(t) = U^{\dagger}(t) O U(t)$ are simultaneously true. If you don't understand why, you should review in detail the difference between the Schrödinger and Heisenberg pictures. This is not a controversial point.

Comment: Alright, I got it, I actually made a mistake in the algebra and equation 2) turned out to be true (which is a mistake, now I see it). Only a Heisenberg evolution for both operators makes it true, as it should be. That's why I was so buffled and didn't understand. It's clear now, I also get the correct Liouville theorem in classical mechanics with this fix. Thanks.